# Using function, after loop, get the same value

Tags: c++

I got the code below. The only question is after the loop, the population is always the same value. What's the problem?

In a population, the birth rate is the percentage increase of the population due to births, and the death rate is the percentage decrease of the population due to deaths. Write a program that displays the size of a population for any number of years. The program should ask for the following data:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
double get_data(double, string, string);
double population(double, double, double, int, int);


int main()
{
    double pop, birth, death;
    int movein, departures, years;
    double newpop;
    int i;

   cout << "This program calculates population change.\n";
    pop = get_data(2,
        "Enter the starting population size: ",
        "Starting population must be 2 or more.");
    birth = get_data(0,
        "Enter the annual birth rate (as % of current population): ",
        "Birth rate percent cannot be negative.");
    death = get_data(0,
        "Enter the annual death rate (as % of current population): ",
        "Death rate percent cannot be negative.");
    movein = get_data(0,
        "How many individuals move into the area each year? ",
        "Arrivals cannot be negative.");
    departures = get_data(0,
        "How many individuals leave the area each year? ",
        "Departures cannot be negative.");
    years = get_data(1,
        "For how many years do you wish to view population changes? ",
        "Years must be one or more.");
    
    cout << endl << endl
         << "Starting population: " << pop << endl;


    for (i = 1; i <= years; i++)
    {
        newpop = population(pop, birth, death, movein, departures);
        cout << "Population at the end of year " << i << " is " << newpop << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;


}

double get_data(double minValue, string prompt, string inputError) 
{
    double input;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> input;
    while (input < minValue)
    {
        cout << inputError 
             << "\nPlease re-enter: ";
        cin >> input;
    }
    return input;
}

double population(double pop, double birth, double death, int movein, int departures)
{
    double newpop = pop + (birth * pop) / 100 - (death * pop) / 100 + movein - departures;
    return newpop;
}
```

Comment: Inside the loop in the `main` function, do you ever modify the variables `pop`, `birth`, `death`, `movein` or `departures`? Perhaps you should pass `newpop` (initialized as `newpop = pop` before the loop) as the first argument?

Comment: You are just calling the same function that runs the same equation on the same numbers. nothing changes as the loop iterates. This could be a recursive function.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: maybe update pop with newpop after population runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you give your function the same input again and again:

```
newpop = population(pop, birth, death, movein, departures);
```

simple fix could be to eliminate variable `newpop`

```
for (i = 1; i <= years; i++)
{
    pop = population(pop, birth, death, movein, departures);
    cout << "Population at the end of year " << i << " is " << pop << endl;
}
```

or if you want to keep it verbose:

```
for (i = 1; i <= years; i++)
{
    newpop = population(pop, birth, death, movein, departures);
    cout << "Population at the end of year " << i << " is " << newpop << endl;
    pop = newpop;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would work too. The problem is he wasn't updating pop.